# Is there a stratum like protocol for Monero mining pools?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, protocol

I'm trying to learn a litle more about how Monero mining pools work.  I'm somewhat familiar with Bitcoin mining pools and the Stratum protocol (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Stratum_mining_protocol) that was developed that allows pools to send work to miners and accept shares.  What's the equivalent protocol in the Monero world of mining pools?

Comment: See newer QA that answers: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10867/what-exactly-do-miners-communicate-with-a-pool

Answer (score 0):

Stratum can be used for monero mining. Stratum is the protocol for communication between miner and mining pool server. getworktemplate is being replaced by stratum. 
Here is a monero miner which uses stratum: https://github.com/sammy007/monero-stratum

Comment: If I"m reading the above right, that project allows you to create a pool that uses stratum as the protocol for announcing jobs and getting work submitted, etc.  But what protocol do most of the major monero mining pools use?  For instance many seem to rely on the Claymore client.  What protocol does that use to communicate with the pools?

Comment: Claymore uses stratum.

Answer (score 0):

In many cryptonight mining related software it called as 'stratum protocol'. For example:
https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig-proxy

so I believe this is the same protocol as in bitcoin, may be with little differencies.

Comment: "I believe this is the same protocol as in bitcoin" <- it's **not** the same as Bitcoin