# Error: Stratum request without method or result field

Tags: monero-stratum

I'm trying to connect to `pool.minexmr.com` with port number `4444`.

I'm using the npm package `stratum` here is the link to the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stratum) and using the example from the example/client.

But I'm receiving an error which I don't understand. The logic is:

```
connect-> authorize -> subscribe -> submit
```

I also tried:

```
connect-> subscribe-> authorize-> submit
```

But that didn't work as well and isn't logical to me.

The code and output is [codepile](https://www.codepile.net/pile/dpM89AqG).

The socket says the authorization is still pending that where the error comes from?

But how do I know when the socket is authorized if `async/await` and `then` not working.

As you can see in the second log from the socket `Authorized` is still false while my console.log says authorized and the socket says that I'm not authorized.

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin's stratum is not the same as Monero's stratum. The node module you are trying to use is a Bitcoin stratum module yet you're trying to use it with a Monero pool. That's the primary reason it's not working for you.

Monero style stratum payloads are shown in this [answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/10869/7493), amongst others.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does all cryptonight/randomX coins have the same stratum payload? Where did you find the payload for Monero because I couldn't find anything. Perhaps I'm searching for the wrong query on Google.

Comment: All the Monero pools use the practically the same stratum payloads. I cant speak for "other" coins, you should ask in their communities, this is a Monero StackExchange site. The two easy ways to find out what payloads are being used is capture the network traffic between miner and pool (as mentioned in the linked answer) or looking at pool/miner source code.